# Chart.js formatting data values

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to give some format to the values that appear when I hover on the bars, [image]

I already formatted the Yaxis using a small function using the userCallback

```
  {
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        userCallback: (value, index, values) => {
          return numberWithCommas(value);
        }
      },
      position: "right",
      gridLines: {
        display: false,
        color: borderColor,
        zeroLineColor: grayColor
      },
      id: 'y-axis-2'
    }
```

But I don't know how to do the same on the values of the hover, any idea?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        return '$' + value;
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Try to replace yAxes to xAxes